How to override a mocked method in a jest.mock'd module in an e2e test with jest.spyOn
I have a mock prisma service in the the __mocks__ folder and am using it in unit tests like this, which works as expected.
// __mocks__/prisma.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService {
  foo = {
    findUnique: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ name: 'foo-mock' })
  }
}

// foo.service.spec.ts

jest.mock('path/to/prisma.service.ts');

...

it('', async () => {
  const actual = await fooService.findOne(123);
  expect(actual).toEqual({ name: 'foo-mock' });
});

it('', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(prismaService.foo, 'findUnique').mockResolvedValue({ name: 'foo-spy' });
  const actual = await fooService.findOne(123);
  expect(actual).toEqual({ name: 'foo-spy' });
});

However, when I do this in an e2e test, the implementation in  mocks doesn't get overridden with the spyOn like it does in unit tests.
// foo.service.e2e-spec.ts

jest.mock('path/to/prisma.service.ts');

beforeEach(async () => {
  const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule]
  }).compile();

  app = module.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();

  prismaServie = app.get<PrismaService>(PrismaService);
  
});

// Fails because name is still 'foo-mock'
it('', () => {
  jest.spyOn(prismaService.foo, 'findUnique').mockResolvedValue({ name: 'foo-spy' });

  return request(app.getHttpServer())
    .get('/foo/123')
    .expect(({ body }) => {
      expect(body).toEqual({ name: 'foo-spy' })
    });
});


Why does it not behave the same as in the unit tests?
